# An Iphone App to access SMS and store it on iCloud

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5

Is it possible to write an Iphone App that can access the SMS Messages on the Phone and store it elsewhere? I have seen other questions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533938/accessing-sms-content-iphone) this and another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290845/how-to-access-and-open-the-iphones-sms-api-from-an-iphone-app) that says one can send SMS with the  MFMessageComposeViewController from the MessageUI Framework.

Since both the questions were more than a year old, is it possible to do this now ( Accessing SMS messages and storing it on the iCloud) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, the iOS SDK does not allow you to access the messages from the messages.app.

Also all message are already backed up to iCloud when a device backup is made.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Dev Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html) says, "In iOS 4.0 and later, you can send text messages from within your application. This feature is strictly for sending messages. Incoming SMS messages go to the built-in Messages app." I wish they would explain why they won't allow programs to access messages.

So not with an iPhone app, apparently, but you can access them with a desktop app. See http://www.wired.com/2013/11/backup-sms-iphone:

"Apple saves your text messages in its iPhone backups, whether they’re saved locally on your PC or whether they’re part of an iCloud backup — which you should have. That’s good! Unfortunately, they’re not separated out. However, you can access them through the filesystem. If you back up locally on an Apple machine, you can find the file under Library > Application Support > MobileSync > Backup. There should be multiple folders there, each with a different backup image of your phone. Each of the folders should have a file named ” 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28.mddata.” Those are your texts, in SQLite database form."

You'll need to use SQLite to decipher the file. There are some instructions here:

[How to Access and Read the iPhone SMS Text Message Backup Files](http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/08/read-iphone-sms-backup/).